# php session_destroy() what does it actually do?

Tags: php, session

I am reading about PHP sessions and am in the section of `session_destroy()`.

Manual states:

> Destroys all data registered to a session

My question is what data? If this function does not destroy the sessions id/cookie what does it actually destroy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a session is created ([`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)) a file is created with a unique identifier that is given to the user as a cookie, when variables in the `$_SESSION` array are modified or added the temporary file is updated with that information so that it can be used somewhere else on the website.

If the user already has a `PHPSESSID` cookie (which is what is given to the user when a session is created) PHP will look through all of the session files for a file with the identifier that is the same value as the cookie. If one is found the information in the file will fill `$_SESSION`, otherwise a new session is created as usual.

[`session_destroy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) will delete this file, this is commonly done for when a user logs out of your website so that the (now useless and unnecessary) file isn't taking up space.

Comment: Might be worth nothing that it `"does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called."` (*taken from [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) docs*). Other than that, this is a perfect answer!